# LZW and CGPDFScanner

Tags: c, lzw, cgpdf

Does CGPDFScanner decompress any LZW-compression it encounters? Or am I responsible for this? [I'm assuming it does because I'm picking up plenty of `Tj` operators etc.]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, `CGPDFScanner` will decompress any compressed streams it finds. You don't need to do that manually.